# Using a script to process form input every time a form is submitted

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-forms, google-apps-script-triggers

I'm trying to have it that every time I submit a form, it adds automatically some data.  This is the script I have:

```
function onFormSubmit(Test) {    
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
  var row =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getLastRow();
  sheet.getRange(row,3).setValue(1);
}
```

Basically, I want to submit the script and the third row will automatically show 1 for every line. The end goal is the add a function in place of 1.  So let say the form is a number, I want the ability to add a function to add 4 to that and display the results.

Answer (score 1):

If the data you want to use is in, say, column E (5th column), then instead of

```
sheet.getRange(row,3).setValue(1);
```

you would have

```
sheet.getRange(row,3).setValue(sheet.getRange(row,5).getValue() + 4);
```

---

Or, if the computation involves several values in that row, say in the first ten columns, then get the row all in once:

```
var values =  sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 10).getValues(); 
var output = values[0][4] + 2*values[0][7] - 3*values[0][9];
sheet.getRange(row, 3).setValue(output);
```

In the latter version, JavaScript array indexing is used, where indices begin at 0, unlike in Sheets. So, `values[0][4]` means the zeroth row, fourth column in the fetched range; in practice, column E of the row that was fetched.

---

Also, the approach with `getLastRow()` may skip some entry if two arrive simultaneously. If you want to guard against that, get all the data and process any rows that aren't yet. Like this:

```
var values =  sheet.getDataRange().getValues(); 
for (var i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
  if (values[0][2] === "") { 
    var output = values[0][4] + 2*values[0][7] - 3*values[0][9];
    sheet.getRange(i+1, 3).setValue(output);
  }
}
```